# Excel files get "corrupted" during upload via swfupload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, swfupload, corruption

I'm using [swfupload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) to upload some excel files to my server.  When the uploaded file is in the old (< 2003) format, everything works fine.  I can upload the file, redownload it, and and confirm it is the same.

The problem is, whenever I upload a file in the new open xml format (> 2007).  When I redownload that file and open it, I get an error:

> Excel found unreadable content in 'filename'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

I checked on the server and confirmed the same error is present there as well.

Additional info:

- The files are stored on the server file system (not DB BLOBs)
- If I "recover" the file, the contents appear to be exactly the same as the originals
- This same system works fine for Excel < 2003 files and image files
- I save the file on the server with `File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data)` where `data` is generated by  `upload.InputStream.Read(data, 0, upload.ContentLength)`

Comment: Are you saying that if you double click the file on the server you get the same error message?  You might want to look at the headers the server is sending: maybe they're wrong for 2007 files...

Comment: Same error when I open the file on my server directly. I'm sending it with MIME type of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Comment: Are you sending an actual filename with the file?  I think there are some changes in Excel 2007 which check the file extension against the file content - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx  Not the exact same error you're seeing but might be related.

Comment: I am setting the file name to the date, followed by the file id, with a xlsx extension.

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any more ideas...